# Stop route navigation after close mat dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, material-design

I have this code :

```
openPopup(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.dialog.closeAll();
    this.modalService.open(
        this.templateModal,
        this.translateService.instant('dialog.project.title'),
        this.translateService.instant('dialog.project.btn_title'),
        null,
        '600'
    );
    return false;
}
```

In the html I have :

```
<a (click)="openPopup($event);">
    {{'dialog.click' | translate}}
</a>
```

After click I close the previous mat dialog, I open a new popup and I'm redirected to an url that I put as callback when the previous is closed. How I can stop this redirect in this function : `openPopup` ? I tried with stopPropagation and preventDefault but no success. Thx in advance and sorry for english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'afterClosed()' method of MatDialog Component and then make a subscription to it. It will be called after the MatDialog is destroyed.

```
this.modalService.open(
        this.templateModal,
        this.translateService.instant('dialog.project.title'),
        this.translateService.instant('dialog.project.btn_title'),
        null,
        '600'
).afterClosed().subscribe(conditionToOpenUrl => {
  if(conditionToOpenUrl) {
    // logic to open url
  }
});
```

The argument 'conditionToOpenUrl' is a parameter you can pass in the 'close()' method of MatDialog.

Comment: The idea is that stopPropagation and preventDefault not working